# ListBox update performance issue using DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, datatemplate

I have a performance issue when rendering the items inside a ListBox (with a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel) and hope someone of you may have an idea how to fix/improve this.

**Scenario**:
In my View I have a ListBox which looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType = MyModel>
      <Chart XAxisMaximum="{Binding Path=DataContext.AxisLimits.XMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode = FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyView}}}" 
             YAxisMaximum="{Binding Path=DataContext.AxisLimits.YMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode = FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyView}}}">
      </Chart>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True">
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

My DataTemplate is a Chart Control where the maximum of the XAxis and YAxis can be bound to some properties on the ViewModel, which works just fine. MyModel contains the ObservableCollection which will be displayed as the DataPoints inside the chart.
Additionally, I have a "Zoom" button which will adjust the XMax and YMax properties on the ViewModel causing an update on the View.
Note that XMax and YMax are not part of MyModel so I have to set the Binding with a RelativeSource.

**The problem:**
As soon as I have about 20 charts inside the zooming gets really slow because the charts will get updated all at once.

**The question:**
Does anybody know a way how I can improve the performance, maybe by sequentially updating each element? I thought about Moving the XMax and YMax properties to MyModel (and then use a DispatcherTimer to update the MyModel objects one after another) but I think its cleaner to have them on the ViewModel. 
Another approach would be to use a VirtualizingWrapPanel like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75847/Virtualizing-WrapPanel?fid=1569947&fr=51#xx0xx), which will probably reduce the performance impact when MyCollection gets large.

Would be interesting to hear about some other ideas.

This is my first question so please tell me if you need more information about my scenario.

Comment: Why `Zoom` is changing all charts? I would try to make it for only selected item (and will have `SelectionMode.Single`). You may have bad performance because of 2 reasons: update of invisible items occurs (use virtualization in this case) or chart control peformance itself (if it takes `100 ms` to redraw only `1` chart, then you will need 2 seconds to redraw `20`, virtualization won't help if all those 20 are visible).

Comment: @Sinatr: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately updating only the selected item is not an option. Every visible chart has to be updated, so I guess using some kind of virtualisation will be necessary for sure. But you are right, even 10 or 20 visible charts will block the UI for 1-2 seconds, that's why I wanted to update one after another. But I am still searching for a good approach on how to do that.